# How to show notification bar for a short time when the window is full screen by default?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-asynctask, android-notifications

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setting fullscreen
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.repository_list);
```

One can see that the window is fullscreen by default.

In an async task,notification is to be shown

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(this_context,"Downloading",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mNotifyManager =
                (NotificationManager) this_context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this_context);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Repository")
                .setContentText("Download in progress")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download);
        mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
        // Displays the progress bar for the first time.
        mNotifyManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        //dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this_context, "Wait", "Downloading...", true);
    }
```

But the window being fullscreen, the notification cant be seen.
How can the notification be seen and then again will be hidden when the onPostExecute method will be called.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok have found an answer.

Have written this code.

On preExecute method

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(this_context,"Downloading",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ((Activity)this_context).getWindow().addFlags((WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN));

        mNotifyManager =
                (NotificationManager) this_context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this_context);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Repository")
                .setContentText("Download in progress")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download);
        mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
        // Displays the progress bar for the first time.
        mNotifyManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        //dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this_context, "Wait", "Downloading...", true);
    }
```

And on postExecute method

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        ((Activity)this_context).getWindow().clearFlags((WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN));
        mBuilder.setContentText("Download complete")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download_done)
                // Removes the progress bar
                .setProgress(0,0,false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        mNotifyManager.cancel(1);
```

So long story short.

1.When activity is started the window was set to flag fullscreen

2.When asyntask starts,on the preexecute method, added the flag to force not fullscreen.Now can see the downloading notification as planned.

3.When asynctask completed downloading,the window flag to force not fullscreen is cleared.And again the window implements the default flag automatically i.e flag fullscreen which was set at the start of the activity.

Thanks for your time.